# GetPrintQueue causes incomplete Form Load execution

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, form-load

I'm calling `GetPrintQueue("Adobe PDF")` in my form `Load` event code to check if the Adobe PDF driver is available.  If I change it to a queue name that doesn't exist, in order to test that condition, any code following that statement doesn't execute and it immediately executes the form `Activated` event.  I'm planning to do a `GetPrintQueues` and search the results instead, but I can't explain the behavior.  This is a Visual Studio 2017 C# Autodesk Inventor addin.

EDIT:

Using this instead.

```
private LocalPrintServer localPrintServer = new LocalPrintServer();
private PrintQueueCollection printQueues;
private PrintQueue pdfPrintQueue;
...
printQueues = localPrintServer.GetPrintQueues();
if (printQueues.Any(n => n.FullName == "Adobe PDF"))
    { pdfPrintQueue = localPrintServer.GetPrintQueue("Adobe PDF"); }
else { pdfPrintQueue = null; }
```

Comment: The load event can swallow some exceptions.  Best not to run code there.  Use the constructor instead.

Comment: Thanks.  It's just odd behavior.  The Microsoft docs don't mention it throwing an exception at all, so I figured it would return null if the queue didn't exist and not complain otherwise.